# focus on user input using Scanner class in java

Tags: java

When using a Scanner object is it possible to ensure the cursor always focuses in the console? For example when I run my program if I do not click in the console and start typing my input ends up in the middle of my program code if I am not paying attention.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = s.nextLine(); 
System.out.print("Enter your name")
```

So when I run this program I will get Enter your name in the console and I would like to automatically focus the cursor ready to take users info at the end of the sentance.

Thanks for any help

Comment: *"I am not paying attention."*  Pay attention.  Computers do not work by magic.

Comment: You may try playing with settings of your IDE. It has nothing to do with java program.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You are correct computers do not work by magic, but the magical thing about computers is that you can program them to do specific things - sometimes. I was wondering if there was a similar command like the one in C# but as other people have pointed out it's down to the environment - not Java.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, at least not in general.  `Scanner` has absolutely nothing to do with the console (it might be reading input from a socket or a file) and even if it is reading from the console, it cannot control your cursor location.

Something like [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) would give you limited ability to control the cursor (via mouse clicks) but it would be very environment specific (what if the user moves the console?  what if they're not even running in the IDE/from the command line?)

You're solving a problem that you don't need to solve, and at a level that shouldn't be cognizant of the problem (if anything, solve this in environment configuration, not in program logic).

Answer (score 1):

As AKJ said, not focusing on the console, totally depends on IDE.
As for your code, it will first wait for the user input then user is prompted. Hence, you might interchange the second and third line of code.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name");
String name = s.nextLine();
```